# Show percentage on Pie chart with multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008-r2, pie-chart, percentage

I have developed piechart in ssrs with multiple datasets. My scenerio is to set Percentage format for values in Piechart. For same dataset the percentage value is showed correctly, but for values fetch from another dataset can't fetch percentage in piechart. For same dataset the value is as following :

```
=Sum(Fields!myValue.Value)
```

For value from another datset:

```
=Sum(Fields!myVal1.Value, "GetMyValue")
```

I set Lable value as "#PERCENT" in series properties. For different dataset, is there anything need to change? can anypne help me to solve this..
I have added the sample report image here. [image: Piechart multiple dataset]
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by setting format :

```
Label - Format : 0.00%
Label - Label  : #PERCENT
```

Now its working as expected.. 
The output sample is added here... [image: Percentage Format]